# Tables not looking uniform on different screen size

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, css-tables

I have a text-filled table divided into 4 columns (as shown in the picture below) which displays all the sub-categories (level 2 and level 3 sub-categories). This table does not look uniform some columns appear longer than others) on different screen sizes (different laptop sizes) and on different devices even after i attempted to make it responsive using @media queries. Is there a way to deal with this, so that all the columns always look uniform?

I have used media

```css
.tblcol {
  width: 22%;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-family: "Palatino Linotype";
}

.heading {
  background-color: #790102;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 2px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.slogan {
  color: #790102;
  letter-spacing: 8px;
  font-size: 18px
}

@media(max-width:1023px) {
  .categoryTable1 {
    width: 500px;
  }
}

@media(min-width:1024px) and (max-width:1010px) {
  .categoryTable1 {
    width: 680px;
  }
}

@media(min-width:1011px) and (max-width:1300px) {
  .categoryTable1 {
    width: 740px;
  }
}

@media(min-width:1224px) and (max-width:1400px) {
  .categoryTable1 {
    width: 850px;
  }
}

@media(min-width:1410px) {
  .categoryTable1 {
    width: 970px;
  }
}
```

```html
<table class="categoryTable1">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4">
      <p style="text-align:center" class="slogan"> 1500+ ITEMS * 45 PRODUCTS * 14 CATEGORIES </p>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td width="25%" class="tblcol">

      <a href="https://www.chinesefashionstyle.com/bespoke-custom-made-services/ " target="_self"> <span class="heading"> BESPOKE CUSTOM MADE SERVICES  </span> </a><br>
      <a href="https://www.chinesefashionstyle.com/bespoke-tailoring-for-women/ " target="_self">   Bespoke Tailoring for Women     </a><br>
      <a href="https://www.chinesefashionstyle.com/bespoke-tailoring-for-men/ " target="_self">    Bespoke Tailoring for Men    </a><br>
      <a href="https://www.chinesefashionstyle.com/made-to-measure-for-juniors/ " target="_self">  Made to Measure for Juniors      </a><br>
      <a href="https://www.chinesefashionstyle.com/bespoke-custom-made-services/ " target="_self"> <span class="heading"> BESPOKE CUSTOM MADE SERVICES  </span> </a><br>
      <a href="https://www.chinesefashionstyle.com/bespoke-tailoring-for-women/ " target="_self">   Bespoke Tailoring for Women     </a><br>
    </td>


    <td width="25%" class="tblcol">

      <a href="https://www.chinesefashionstyle.com/bespoke-custom-made-services/ " target="_self"> <span class="heading"> BESPOKE CUSTOM MADE SERVICES  </span> </a><br>
      <a href="https://www.chinesefashionstyle.com/bespoke-tailoring-for-women/ " target="_self">   Bespoke Tailoring for Women     </a><br>
      <a href="https://www.chinesefashionstyle.com/bespoke-tailoring-for-men/ " target="_self">    Bespoke Tailoring for Men    </a><br>
      <a href="https://www.chinesefashionstyle.com/made-to-measure-for-juniors/ " target="_self">  Made to Measure for Juniors      </a><br>
      <a href="https://www.chinesefashionstyle.com/bespoke-custom-made-services/ " target="_self"> <span class="heading"> BESPOKE CUSTOM MADE SERVICES  </span> </a><br>
      <a href="https://www.chinesefashionstyle.com/bespoke-tailoring-for-women/ " target="_self">   Bespoke Tailoring for Women     </a><br>

    </td>


    <td width="25%" class="tblcol">

      <a href="https://www.chinesefashionstyle.com/bespoke-custom-made-services/ " target="_self"> <span class="heading"> BESPOKE CUSTOM MADE SERVICES  </span> </a><br>
      <a href="https://www.chinesefashionstyle.com/bespoke-tailoring-for-women/ " target="_self">   Bespoke Tailoring for Women     </a><br>
      <a href="https://www.chinesefashionstyle.com/bespoke-tailoring-for-men/ " target="_self">    Bespoke Tailoring for Men    </a><br>
      <a href="https://www.chinesefashionstyle.com/made-to-measure-for-juniors/ " target="_self">  Made to Measure for Juniors      </a><br>
      <a href="https://www.chinesefashionstyle.com/bespoke-custom-made-services/ " target="_self"> <span class="heading"> BESPOKE CUSTOM MADE SERVICES  </span> </a><br>
      <a href="https://www.chinesefashionstyle.com/bespoke-tailoring-for-women/ " target="_self">   Bespoke Tailoring for Women     </a><br>
    </td>


    <td width="25%" class="tblcol">

      <a href="https://www.chinesefashionstyle.com/bespoke-custom-made-services/ " target="_self"> <span class="heading"> BESPOKE CUSTOM MADE SERVICES  </span> </a><br>
      <a href="https://www.chinesefashionstyle.com/bespoke-tailoring-for-women/ " target="_self">   Bespoke Tailoring for Women     </a><br>
      <a href="https://www.chinesefashionstyle.com/bespoke-tailoring-for-men/ " target="_self">    Bespoke Tailoring for Men    </a><br>
      <a href="https://www.chinesefashionstyle.com/made-to-measure-for-juniors/ " target="_self">  Made to Measure for Juniors      </a><br>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

queries to update the table width to fit the size as required. But when the table width is reduced; the 4 columns are non-uniform: some much larger than the others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.slogan {
  color: #790102;
  letter-spacing: 8px;
  font-size: 18px
}

.heading {
  background-color: #790102;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 2px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td,
th {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-family: "Palatino Linotype";
}
```

```html
<table class="categoryTable1">

  <tr>
    <td colspan="4">
      <p style="text-align:center" class="slogan">1500+ ITEMS * 45 PRODUCTS * 14 CATEGORIES</p>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="https://www.chinesefashionstyle.com/bespoke-custom-made-services/ " target="_self">
        <span class="heading">BESPOKE CUSTOM MADE SERVICES</span>
      </a>
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href="https://www.chinesefashionstyle.com/bespoke-custom-made-services/ " target="_self">
        <span class="heading">BESPOKE CUSTOM MADE SERVICES</span>
      </a>
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href="https://www.chinesefashionstyle.com/bespoke-custom-made-services/ " target="_self">
        <span class="heading">BESPOKE CUSTOM MADE SERVICES</span>
      </a>
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href="https://www.chinesefashionstyle.com/bespoke-custom-made-services/ " target="_self">
        <span class="heading">BESPOKE CUSTOM MADE SERVICES</span>
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="https://www.chinesefashionstyle.com/bespoke-tailoring-for-women/ " target="_self">Bespoke Tailoring for Women</a>
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href="https://www.chinesefashionstyle.com/bespoke-tailoring-for-women/ " target="_self">Bespoke Tailoring for Women</a>
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href="https://www.chinesefashionstyle.com/bespoke-tailoring-for-women/ " target="_self">Bespoke Tailoring for Women</a>
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href="https://www.chinesefashionstyle.com/bespoke-tailoring-for-women/ " target="_self">Bespoke Tailoring for Women</a>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="https://www.chinesefashionstyle.com/bespoke-tailoring-for-men/ " target="_self">Bespoke Tailoring for Men</a>
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href="https://www.chinesefashionstyle.com/bespoke-tailoring-for-men/ " target="_self">Bespoke Tailoring for Men</a>
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href="https://www.chinesefashionstyle.com/bespoke-tailoring-for-men/ " target="_self">Bespoke Tailoring for Men</a>
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href="https://www.chinesefashionstyle.com/bespoke-tailoring-for-men/ " target="_self">Bespoke Tailoring for Men</a>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="https://www.chinesefashionstyle.com/made-to-measure-for-juniors/ " target="_self">Made to Measure for Juniors</a>
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href="https://www.chinesefashionstyle.com/made-to-measure-for-juniors/ " target="_self">Made to Measure for Juniors</a>
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href="https://www.chinesefashionstyle.com/made-to-measure-for-juniors/ " target="_self">Made to Measure for Juniors</a>
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href="https://www.chinesefashionstyle.com/made-to-measure-for-juniors/ " target="_self">Made to Measure for Juniors</a>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="https://www.chinesefashionstyle.com/bespoke-custom-made-services/ " target="_self">
        <span class="heading">BESPOKE CUSTOM MADE SERVICES</span>
      </a>
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href="https://www.chinesefashionstyle.com/bespoke-custom-made-services/ " target="_self">
        <span class="heading">BESPOKE CUSTOM MADE SERVICES</span>
      </a>
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href="https://www.chinesefashionstyle.com/bespoke-custom-made-services/ " target="_self">
        <span class="heading">BESPOKE CUSTOM MADE SERVICES</span>
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="https://www.chinesefashionstyle.com/bespoke-tailoring-for-women/ " target="_self">Bespoke Tailoring for Women</a>
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href="https://www.chinesefashionstyle.com/bespoke-tailoring-for-women/ " target="_self">Bespoke Tailoring for Women</a>
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href="https://www.chinesefashionstyle.com/bespoke-tailoring-for-women/ " target="_self">Bespoke Tailoring for Women</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Now all the columns will look uniform.
The HTML  element defines a row of cells in a table. The row's cells can then be established using a mix of  (data cell) and  (header cell) elements.
You could learn more about HTML tables using below link
[Click here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp)

Comment: Thanks Shyam, but my concern is when the window is resized. The table columns don't look uniform anymore. Do you have any suggestions of how to deal with this?

Comment: Could you share any image of a table similar to your expectation?